# RegEx for Oauth HTTP Authorisation header in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I’m trying to deconstruct my HTTP header ‘Authorisation’ in PHP so decided to use a RegEx, but (I’m quite new so forgive me) it only returns the first match rather than all that match.

Here’s my RegEx:

```
(oauth_\w+)=([^"]+),?
```

Here’s a test string:

```
oauth_nonce=AB00E4270DF844E1882E25D19905350A,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_timestamp=1418827216.70618,oauth_signature=UpUl8GDANYML+xivYEdWZjO1U6A=,oauth_consumer_key=publica5d53e674542272aefc2ea8ebf99bf9d771ed2b089bdfd1fbb74b5de69,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
```

PHP Code:

```
preg_match_all('/(oauth_\w+)=([^"]+),?/', getallheaders()['Authorization'], $authorization_values, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

And here’s what is output from the PHP method

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => oauth_nonce=AB00E4270DF844E1882E25D19905350A,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_timestamp=1418827216.70618,oauth_signature=UpUl8GDANYML+xivYEdWZjO1U6A=,oauth_consumer_key=publica5d53e674542272aefc2ea8ebf99bf9d771ed2b089bdfd1fbb74b5de69,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => oauth_nonce
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => AB00E4270DF844E1882E25D19905350A,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_timestamp=1418827216.70618,oauth_signature=UpUl8GDANYML+xivYEdWZjO1U6A=,oauth_consumer_key=publica5d53e674542272aefc2ea8ebf99bf9d771ed2b089bdfd1fbb74b5de69,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(oauth_\w+)=([^",]+),?
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/39

Comment: Only one character out! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, at the time I had to wait before accepting the answer